# Unique Value Function in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I created the following function using Excel 2010.  It seem to work only when i use the function in the same sheet the array was created (sheet2) and if a value is typed in the function e.g.: =KeyExists(1443).  I need to use this function in another sheet within the workbook and needs to be a cell reference.  Stumped on why its not working.

```
Option Explicit
Function KeyExists(k)

Dim d As Object
Dim c As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim msg As String


Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lr = WorkSheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c = Range("A2:A" & lr)

For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
   d(c(i, 1)) = 1
Next i


If d.exists(k) Then
    msg = "key exists"
Else
    msg = "key does not exist"
End If KeyExists = msg

End Function

'parts of the code derived from:
'hiker95, 07/26/2012
'http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?649576-Extract-unique-values-from-one-column-using-VBA
```

Comment: when you look for your last row `lr = WorkSheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` you always reference `Sheet2`. If you would replace it by `ActiveSheet` then it should work: `lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: As far as the second problem goes, perhaps you can insert the qualifier `ByVal` before the parameter `k` in the function header and include the line `If TypeName(k) = "Range" Then k = k.Value`. I'm guessing that `d.exists(k)` is balking at being passed a range.

Comment: I will use this function in other worksheets in this workbook.  I want to use the values in the range in sheet2.  For example, i want to test whether an unique value in sheet2.Range(A2:A") matches to a value in Sheet1.Range("A18").  So in a cell in Sheet1, i will enter =KeyExists(A18)

Comment: You need to include the part @JohnColeman pointed out. Additionally, you will have to specify, from which sheet you call the `.Range` Method, therefore you should set your variable `c` like this: `c = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lr)`

Comment: Surely you don't need a dictionary for this?  As soon as you find a match for k you could exit the first loop...

Comment: With a Scripting.Dictionary object, you add items by `.Add Key, Value`. Your `c` is always a Range object unless you put `.Value` after the range. Also if you use this UDF many times, you are creating the dictionary that many times.

Answer (score 0):

Change it from `Sheet2` to the active sheet:

```
lr = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

If the unique Keys are only in Sheet2 Column A2 and onward... You can create a dynamic named Range and reference it anywhere in the Workbook.

Say you have data:
[image: sampledata]

Create a dynamic named range **`Keys`** with `=OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$A:$A)-1,1)`.

Then say you want to check for values in C4, use formula below:
`=IF(ISNUMBER(IFERROR(MATCH(C4,Keys,0),"")),"key exists","key does not exists")`

There is no need to use VBA for what you want to achieve your goal. e.g.
[image: sample2]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with commenters regarding the `Dictionary`. In my opinion, it would be much easier to do without it. I also think other ways would be vastly quicker, depending on how much data you have.

Example:

```
Function KeyExists(k As Range) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, i As Long

    ' Set ws to the worksheet to which k belongs. 
    ' This avoids activeworksheet and also allows for 
    ' qualified references to other sheets if necessary.
    ws = k.Worksheet

    Set c = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    On Error Resume Next
    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(k.Value, c, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If i <> 0 Then
        KeyExists = "Key exists"
    Else
        KeyExists = "Key does not exist"
    End If
End Function
```

Using `MATCH` will most likely be a lot faster than adding every entry of data into a `Dictionary`.

A case where you might argue using `Dictionary` is marginally better, is if you want to make sure the value is unique. But even then, you'd have to use round-about logic to deal with the what-if of encountering duplicate keys and what to do at that point.

Your question does not really specifiy whether or not you need to perform this check or not, or what to do if duplicates are found, so it's hard to advise on it. In any case, if you opt for this method I would recommend creating a separate procedure that declares and builds the dictionary and run it on `Worksheet_Open` or something like that, leaving you to use a very short function for querying the existence of a key. This circumvents you having to build the dictionary every time the formula runs and will most likely be faster (and require more coding) than my solution.